# Auto-connecting to specific device with serialport in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I am pretty new to node and asynchronous programming (I come from a C background), and I am having trouble auto-connecting to a port that has a device with a certain vendorID using serialport in Node.js. I have everything working separately, ie. I can connect to a port, and I can find a port with a certain vendorID, but I can not connect to the port that I found. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');

var MYport;

SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    if(port.vendorId == 9999){
      console.log('Found It')
      MYport = port.comName.toString();
      console.log(MYport);
    }
  });
});

var port = new SerialPort(MYport, {
  parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\n')
});
```

When this is run I get an error due to the fact that MYport is not defined at the time that the port is created and connected to.

I know that I will most likely have to use a call back function but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SerialPort.list is async function,

so you need place the connection to serialport after emit callback of async function.

like this:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');

var MYport;

SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    if(port.vendorId == 9999){
      console.log('Found It')
      MYport = port.comName.toString();
      console.log(MYport);
    }
  });

  var port = new SerialPort(MYport, {
    parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\n')
  });

});
```

Comment: Ok, I see. I also added a port.on function to gather data and included that again within the list function and everything is working now. It just is so un-intuitive for me. Thanks for the help!